# Establishing a 'weak' union without knowing elements

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I am wondering if there is a canonical name for the following operation/condition. I imagine it as a kind of generalized Union operation for cases where element labels are unknown.

Suppose I know that $X \subset Z$ ($X$ is a subset of $Z$ - all of $X$'s elements are also elements of $Z$ - but I don't know *which* elements of $Z$), and that $Y \subset Z.$

I also know that, for any other subset that shares elements with $Z$ (any $S\sim Z$), that subset also shares elements with $X$ and/or $Y.$

This condition is weaker than the union operation, but any $X,Y,Z$ where $X \cup Y = Z$ will satisfy it.

What do we call this? I'd like to learn more about how it shows up in esp. topology.

Thanks.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but why is this condition weaker than the union? Also, when you write "... for any other subset that shares elements with $Z$..." do you mean that $S\subset Z?$

Comment: By S~Z, I mean any subset S that overlaps with Z in any way (partially, or as a subset or superset). What is this condition, where X < Z, Y < Z, and for any S~Z, it must be that S~X and/or S~Y? This applies to the condition where Union (X,Y) = Z, but also to other conditions which is why I called it 'weaker' (forgive my poor language).

Comment: So the proper way to write that is $S\cap Z\not=\varnothing.$ And, as Alex showed, the condition you have described _is equivalent to_ union.

Answer (score 1):

This condition is *not* weaker than $X\cup Y = Z$.

Suppose $X$, $Y$, $Z$ satisfy your condition. Since $X\subseteq Z$ and $Y\subseteq Z$, we have $X\cup Y\subseteq Z$. So suppose for contradiction that $X\cup Y\neq Z$. Then there is some $z\in Z$ which is not in $X$ or $Y$. The set $S = \{z\}$ shares elements with $Z$, but it does not share elements with either $X$ or $Y$, contradicting your condition.

Your language "for cases where element labels are unknown" and "all of $X$'s elements are also elements of $Z$ - but I don't know which elements of $Z$" suggests to me that you're confused about the basics of set theory. The operation of union is not defined by manipulating element labels, and the subset relation is not defined by listing elements.

Comment: Yes I'm not well versed, I'm a neuro professor not a mathematician.

By labels I mean the knowing of which members are which. I must know this to state e.g. x is an element of X and of Z (right?).

By weaker maybe I mean 'more general'. The condition I stated applies to unions (any set that overlaps Z must overlap X and/or Y, while X and Y both < Z). Your example would fail both my condition and is not a union.

Forget 'elements': if I know about all the overlaps and inclusions of a group of subsets, what can I call this condition I describe, that applies at least to unions?

Thanks!

Comment: @Andrew In the comments above, you wrote "This applies to the condition where Union (X,Y) = Z, but also to other conditions." What other conditions do you have in mind? The point of my answer is to prove that it applies *only* to unions.